# react-native-reanimated:mergeDebugJniLibFolders

Tags: react-native

I try install react-native-reanimated and occurred:

> Task :react-native-reanimated:mergeDebugJniLibFolders
> Execution optimizations have been disabled for task ':react-native-reanimated:mergeDebugJniLibFolders' to ensure correctness due to the following reasons:

- Gradle detected a problem with the following location: 'C:...\node_modules\react-native-reanimated\android\src\main\jniLibs'. Reason: Task '**:react-native-reanimated:mergeDebugJniLibFolders**' uses this output of task '**:react-native-reanimated:packageNdkLibs**' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency for more details about this problem.

The app build but it open and close then.

[Build Successful](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tsgHH.png)

I want build a QRcodeReader and 'react-native-reanimated' is a dependecy to anothers.

My package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.17.11",
    "@react-native-community/geolocation": "^3.0.5",
    "@react-native-community/slider": "^4.4.2",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.5",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.6.1",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.4",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.12",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.14",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.2",
    "axios": "^1.3.3",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.71.3",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.9.0",
    "react-native-hole-view": "^2.2.0",
    "react-native-maps": "^1.4.0",
    "react-native-permissions": "^3.8.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^3.0.2",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.5.0",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.20.0",
    "react-native-sweet-alert": "^3.5.0",
    "react-native-text-input-mask": "^3.1.4",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.2.0",
    "react-native-vision-camera": "^2.15.4",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.5",
    "redux": "^4.2.1",
    "vision-camera-code-scanner": "^0.2.0"
  }
```

To fix this erro I try:

1. run `./gradlew clean` .
2. I read https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency  but I not undestand how to fix this error.
3. I Try [Remove Implicit Dependency warning from Gradle output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72194499/remove-implicit-dependency-warning-from-gradle-output) but I dont know where insert the modify propose (with adaptations to my problem)